# "See Through" Effect programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, image, effect

In Xcode how can I make the "See through" effect like in this image:

[image: Arc de Triomphe]

Like if the text was a hole in the overlay color.   I need to do this programmatically to display different text.

Comment: Read up on layer masking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGImages can have a separate image mask, which is a 8-bit grayscale image. So draw the text into a grayscale CGBitmapContext. Make a CGImageRef out of it. Attach the image as a mask to the image and draw over a blue field.  If you prefer, you can attach the mask to the blue field and draw it on top of the image.